# How to show Published date and/or Modified date

Tags: post-meta, date-time, wp-update-post

My code is based on the underscores reference theme.
I have a `posted_on` function as follows:

```
function example_posted_on() {
        $time_string = '<time class="entry-date published updated" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time>';
        if ( get_the_time( 'U' ) !== get_the_modified_time( 'U' ) ) {
            $time_string = '<time class="entry-date published" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time><time class="updated" datetime="%3$s">%4$s</time>';
        }

$time_string = sprintf( $time_string,
    esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
    esc_html( get_the_date() ),
    esc_attr( get_the_modified_date( 'c' ) ),
    esc_html( get_the_modified_date() )
);

    $posted_on = sprintf(
    ' %s',
    $time_string
);

echo '<span class="posted-on">' . $posted_on . '</span>';  //WPCS: XSS  OK.
}
```

The result is that `example_posted_on()` correctly displays only the published date.
My questions are: Why does it get the modified date anyway?
How is it possible to show the modified date in addition or instead the published date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function should be displaying both modified and published dates only if they differ.

```
    if ( get_the_time( 'U' ) !== get_the_modified_time( 'U' ) ) {
        $time_string = '<time class="entry-date published" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time><time class="updated" datetime="%3$s">%4$s</time>';
    }
```

Dates are compared using timestamps and if they don't match the string format is set to two `<time>` tags otherwise it's just published date.

Comment: I agree, but it doesn't. If I edit a post and hit the update button, the post just shows the initial date.

Comment: Is it an already published post or a draft?

Comment: Already published.

Comment: @IXN it hidden by your css

Comment: @Jevuska That's probably it.

Comment: How can I keep the two separate intentionally? Publish date being the original publish date. Not the modified date which can keep changing.